# Is it possible to display an image in text field in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

Can we display image inside a text field in `html`?

**Edit**

What I want to do is to have an `editable` area, and want to add `html` objects inside it(i.e. button, image ..etc)

Comment: your question is not clear at all, at least not clear to me...could you clear it a bit

Comment: @Sudhir It's pretty simple... As I understand, Bader just wants to put an image inside a text field (`<input>`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Image in text field:**

You can do it with CSS.

Look this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/zy7YP/1/

**CSS:**

```
.icon {
    background:#FFFFFF url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/gakuseisean/ivista-2/16/Start-Menu-Search-icon.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
    height:18px;
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="sample" class="icon">​
```

---

According to your post edit, maybe this helps.

**Editable area with objects inside:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/VSWNX/

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.

Comment: What if I want to have two different images on the same textbox(one on the leftside and the other one on the rightside within the textbox)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it using HTML I guess the better way would be to keep the image next to the form element and then using css position:relative property place it inside the text field. Not elegant but works in most cases.